# Trouble using JRun to Host Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, hosting, jrun

I am deploying new versions of java servlets with JRun as the host. I am having difficulty finding good sources for information about JRun and tutorials about how to configure and manage it.

After installing JRun and opening the launcher it can't start the admin server that it creates by default...so obviously I'm running into some issues just getting started.

**edit for clarity:** I'm not looking for an answer or help with a specific error but if anyone knows of good sources for information about JRun and how to work with it so I can quickly bring myself up to speed on it.

Answer (score 2):

[Jrun development has pretty much stopped](http://www.adobe.com/products/jrun/productinfo/faq/eod/). You should look into running another application server. [Jboss](http://www.jboss.org/) or [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) are good alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to be difficult to resolve unless you post either the error message from the log file or the list of steps that you took so far.

I have JRun 3.1 configured on my machine so maybe I can duplicate your issue if you give us more information.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know JRun was even still in existence since 1999 or something like that. Anyway, [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jetty](http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty/) would be my easy replacements. Tomcat for its scriptability from ANT etc and Jetty for its pure simplicity (start an instance in 5 lines of code!).

[Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) is a huge system with many components, if you just want to host vanilla servlets and JSPs etc. then I would go for one of the above.